# XSLT: How do I match every descendant individually?

Tags: xslt, descendant

I am attempting to flatten the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://pretend.namespace">
    <record>
        <first>1</first>
        <second>2</second>
        <tricky>
            <taxing>3</taxing>
            <mayhem>
                <ohno>4</ohno>
                <boom>5</boom>
            </mayhem>
        </tricky>
    </record>
    <record>
        <first>1</first>
        <second>2</second>
        <tricky>
            <taxing>3</taxing>
            <mayhem>
                <ohno>4</ohno>
                <boom>5</boom>
            </mayhem>
        </tricky>
    </record>
    <record>
        <first>1</first>
        <second>2</second>
        <tricky>
            <taxing>3</taxing>
            <mayhem>
                <ohno>4</ohno>
                <boom>5</boom>
            </mayhem>
        </tricky>
    </record>
</root>
```

into one row-per record, discarding the complex structure within the records.

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
```

using this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:p="http://pretend.namespace">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> <!-- remove unwanted whitespace? -->

 <!-- Match every p:record -->
<xsl:template match="p:record">
    <xsl:apply-templates/> <!-- now we're inside a <record> do what you can with the contents then give a line return -->
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text><!-- this is a line return -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p:record//*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/> <!-- WORKS: prevents "default output" to aid debugging -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but despite hours of trying I cannot get it to visit each descendant and comma-separate them all, and I get this:

```
1,2,345,
1,2,345,
1,2,345,
```

What do I need to do to get it to treat all the grandchildren and below individually? (The final comma per line isn't an issue)

Thank you!

EDIT: The discussion following this question indicated that Dr. Herong Yang's XML Tools for Notepad++ *appears* to only support XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="record">
  <xsl:value-of select="descendant::text()/data()" separator=","/>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

(The explicit atomization using `data()` is needed because otherwise, adjacent text nodes are concatenated without a separator).

Comment: Thank you. Notepad++'s XML tools states "unable to apply, make sure XSL is valid" unless I remove ``/data()`` (which defeats the point). Is it possible Notepad++ is not a complete implementation?

Comment: @Mike, `data()` is a function introduced in XPath/XSLT 2.0, like the `separator` attribute so if you get errors then your editor likely only supports XSLT 1.0 or is at least configured by default only to support XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @Mike, XSLT 2.0 has been around for 10 years+, if you are constrained to use an older version you need to say so.

Comment: Thanks both - it seems likely from this that Dr. Yang's XML Tools Plugin for Notepad++ only supports XSLT 1.0. I wasn't aware - it isn't clearly documented whether that's the case. Hopefully this discussion will help other people identify this limitation!

Comment: Marking as correct but disclaimer: I have not tried this in an XSLT 2.0 processor yet

Answer (score 0):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:p="http://pretend.namespace">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="p:record">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, 

I don't understand the XPath expression ``*[not(*)]`` What does it mean, please? I read it as "Everything except everything"! 

EDIT: If I had to guess, maybe it means "All children excluding all children (of the child)" thus making the match less greedy?

Comment: It means an element with no child elements - it's actually short for `*[not(child::*)]`. There is an assumption here that every leaf node is a data cell.

Comment: Thank you again. This has comma-separated the leaves as desired, but the attempt to insert a line return after the final child of each record no longer works.

For future referencers: (I removed your 'if last' test due to a structure I failed to reflect in the example: in the real data there are more than one "deepest" structures within the record and this was omitting the comma after each of them)

Comment: You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/93dEHGm If you input is different, then edit your question and clarify - or post a new one.

Comment: Thank you - if I find the difference I'll update this

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I have decided from the discussion above that I should try to find a (user friendly) processor that supports at least XSLT 2.0, for this kind of usage. I'm afraid I don't have time to identify the differing behaviour between your demonstration and my own in a reasonable timeframe, but I hope this discussion helps someone else in future.